# Echo data from several sql tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have never tried this but want to echo data from several different tables and order them by their timestamp. The code I have comes up with a booleon and i dont know why.

```
 <?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM artists ORDER BY timestamp DESC
UNION
SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY timestamp DESC
UNION
SELECT * FROM tracks ORDER BY timestamp DESC
UNION
SELECT * FROM gigs ORDER BY timestamp DESC
UNION
SELECT * FROM feature ORDER BY timestamp DESC");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){echo'News: <a      href="index.html">'.$row['name'].$row['title'].$row['trackname'].$row['gigname'].'</a><br>'     ;}

?>
```

Comment: Do you know that each SELECT statement within the UNION must have the same number of columns. The columns must also have similar data types. Also, the columns in each SELECT statement must be in the same order? To select data from different tables consider using JOINs.

Comment: select * is usually a bad idea even when not using union

Comment: I did not know that. I've never used a UNSION before. How can I achieve what i want without those requirements?

Comment: so i switched the * for the column i wanted to fetch in each statement but still comes up with booleon

Comment: try adding "or die(mysql_error());" to the end of your mysql_query();

$result = mysql_query($yoursql) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: Please post the structures of each table you unite and read again @Nazin 's comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your tables fall within the constraints of the UNION function..

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM artists ORDER BY timestamp DESC
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM news ORDER BY timestamp DESC
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM tracks ORDER BY timestamp DESC
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM gigs ORDER BY timestamp DESC
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM feature ORDER BY timestamp DESC) as temp
ORDER by timestamp DESC;
```

Comment: Each table did not follow the constraints of a union so have had to order them seperately. Is there an AJAX solution? It should work similar to facebooks news feed